# convert this code from php to .net

Tags: php, .net, asp.net

i am not a php guy so i am not sure what is doing here, can anybody help me convert this below code to .net?

```
 PHP Process Page:

    <?php
     $Name = $_GET["Name"];
     $Message = $_GET["Message"];

     echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] . "({"Name": "" . $Name . "", "Message": "" . $Message . ""})";
    ?>
```

Comment: It's taking URL arguments and outputting them to the browser in Json format. Never used .NET.

Comment: i dont want to use php so what should i do, i am using jquery,.net so what the above code should be look like in .net thats what i meant to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply gets the `Name` and `Message` parameters that were passed in to the page on the query string, then constructs a JSON string from them and outputs them.

In C#:

```
var name = Request.QueryString["Name"];
var message = Request.QueryString["Message"];
var json = Request.QueryString["jsoncallback"];
Response.Write(string.Format("{0}(\{\"Name\": {1}, \"Message\": {2} \})", 
            json, name, message));
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim name as String = Request.QueryString["Name"]
Dim message as String = Request.QueryString["Message"]
Dim json as String = Request.QueryString["jsoncallback"]
Response.Write(string.Format("{0}(\{\"Name\": {1}, \"Message\": {2} \})", 
            json, name, message))
```

Comment: Not "either" query string or form posts, just query string. GET is the http request method used when a query string is passed. (though technically you could have a query string with a POST request) If you wanted either you would use: `$_REQUEST["Name"]`

Comment: @Chicagoland - It is. Why do you think it isn't? You can access query string parameters on the server side.

Comment: +1 for explanation & code. Is that JScript? Though technically not a json string, that's actual javascript code with a JSON object being passed as the argument to the function supplied in `jsoncallback`.

Comment: Remove the semicolons from the VB. I didn't realize you could implicitly type variables in C#. Glad I do now, though.

Comment: @sholsinger - They are still strongly typed, the compiler simply _infers_ the type and the IDE helps... You can lookup the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type.

Answer (score 3):

`string Name = Request["Name"].ToString();

string Message = Request["Message"].ToString();

string jsoncallback =  Request["jsoncallback"].ToString();

Response.Write( jsoncallback + "({'Name': '" + Name + "', 'Message': '" + Message + "'})" );`

Comment: I hope Chicagoland understands C# ;P

Comment: you are right about the `"` (i fixed that :p [enter careless mistake]), why does `{` or `}` need to be escaped, my app just built with them in a string without escaping it (I quickly added it as a test variable for this)

Answer (score 1):

Im not a .NET guy, but I understand whats there ;)

*$_GET* contains every query argument, so if you call this script via

```
http://example.com/script.php?Name=MyName&Message=Hello+World&jsoncallback=myCallback
```

*$_GET['Name']* (and then *$Name*) will contain "MyName", *$_GET['Messafe']* (and then *$Message*) will contain "Hello World" and *$_GET['jsoncallback']* "myCallback". So at all this script will return something like

```
myCallback({Name: MyName, Message: "Hello World"})
```

You can see the three values "myCallback", "MyName" and "Hello World" in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
string strName=string.Empty;
string strMessage=string.Empty;
string strCallBack=string.Empty;

if(Request.QueryString["Name"]!=null)
{         
   strName=Request.QueryString["Name"];
}
if(Request.QueryString["Message"]!=null)
{         
   strName=Request.QueryString["Message"];
}
if(Request.QueryString["jsonCallback"]!=null)
{         
   strCallBack=Request.QueryString["jsonCallback"];
}

Response.Write(strCallBack+"({\"Name\":\""+strName+"\" ,\"Message\": "\"+strMessage+"\"})";
```

Comment: In your `Response.Write` you are not outputting the correct json string.

Comment: @Oded : Thanks for noticing.I was lazy to run the code to see if its correct

Comment: still no good. JSON requires `"`, not `'` and there are no spaces in `"Message"`.